# Fabric: Set configuration variables per-host outside task

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

This question is similar to - [Pass parameter to fabric task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960777/pass-parameter-to-fabric-task)

My problem is that I want to deploy my `sphinx html documentation` to a `remote server`.

I also want to define a remote directory where i copy the files to, for each host separately, outside the task function, preferably also outside the `fabfile`.

Comment: Thank you @DanielNova for the edit. Not sure why you wrote some things in code style, but whatever.

Comment: So your question is how to read variables/settings from outside the fabfile in order to change parameters?

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to make it stand out a bit more for people glancing at it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes, probably. However, i want to do it the way it should be done in fabric, otherwise i also could stick with my bash helper scripts.

Comment: @DanielNova I didn't complain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary if the hosts and paths are known ahead of time or could be computed. EG:

```
env.sphinx_path = {
    'hosta': 'patha',
    'hostb': 'pathb',
}

@task
@hosts('hosta','hostb')
def foo(dummy_var):
    put('sphinx_stuff', env.sphinx_path%env.host)
```

Otherwise you could just pass the path like:

```
fab foo:'sphinx/path'
```

And that would populate dummy_var in the above example for you to then use in the task.

Comment: Seems like that's the only way to do it in fabric. Thanks.

Comment: Well you could also feed in a file, or have it call some database, or GET from a url. Pretty much anything python can do to get you a list or value, you can use.

Comment: I know, right, but i thought there may be some sort of per-host configuration storage in the .fabricrc or something.